# this.$router.push когда у child есть свои children Vue.js/Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

Есть роутер Vue index.js:

```
routes: [
    path: "/",
    name: "main",
    component: Main,
    children: [
        {
          path: 'clients',
          name: 'clients',
          component: ClientsSettings
        },
        {
          path: 'pm-area',
          name: 'pm-area',
          component: PmArea,
          children: [
            {
              path: 'create-project',
              name: 'create-project',
              component: Clientrequest
            }
          ]
        },
    ]
]
```

Если я в коде использую переход к `clients` или `pm-area` с помощью `this.$router.push('clients'), this.$router.push('pm-area')`, то я без проблем перехожу от одного к другому компоненту. Но если я укажу путь `this.$router.push('pm-area/create-project)`, то я перейду к этому компоненту, но уже из него с помощью, например `this.$router.push('clients)` я не попаду в компонент Clients, потому что путь получится следующий `localhost:3001/pm-area/clients`, а должно быть `localhost:3001/clients`. Как правильно переходить между компонентами в таком случае вложенности путей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'clients' })
```

У вас же все роуты именованые. В чем проблема?

Comment: В одном старом известном фильме было: "Болван" - "Согласен" ))

Comment: Бывает ))) Кстати @Илья-Зеленько тоже правильно ответил.

Comment: Да. Это я ступил. Но два ответа принять не вариант. ))

Answer (score 2):

Вы указываете относительный путь, а хотите получить абсолютный.

```
this.$router.push('/clients)
```

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. Спасибо.